# how refresh page not only 1 frame

Tags: html

i have 3 frame in home page.
in third frame is logout link
logout link

```
<a href="./manage/logout.php">logout</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?PHP
require_once("../../include/membersite_config.php");
$fgmembersite->LogOut();
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("http://localhost/");
exit;
}  
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<?PHP
require_once("include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("./pages/manage/login.php");
exit;
}

?>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<frameset cols="70%,30%">
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
<frame src="pages/blank.php" name="frame1">
<frame src="pages/blank.php" name="frame2">
</frameset>
<frame src="pages/main.php" name="frame3">
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

this code only change frame 3 and open login.php page
and 2 other frames dont change,
i want open only page login.php with out any frame .
login.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should put your page in the main page containing your 3 frames.

```
<a href="./manage/logout.php" target="_top">logout</a>
```